# WP REST API returns incorrect data?

Tags: rest-api

I'm trying to get a page from the API based on its page template however it seems to be returning incorrect data? so I'm unsure whether I am using the API correctly.

```
http://domain.dev/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?template=page-contact.php
```

Returns pages using different page templates?

Also if I was to query by page id, it brings back pages which are not the id of 20?

```
http://autosmart.dev/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?id=20
```

Can anyone advise how to get the API to work correctly and whether I am querying the data correctly?

Thanks

Comment: how about `http://autosmart.dev/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/20` , what you got?

Comment: Yeah that worked :) Just that I need to get the page by the page template :/

Comment: in your case, It's about filtering https://github.com/WP-API/rest-filter, but from wp-json/wp/v2/pages you can search the object for specific template.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was unable to download the plugin :( The package could not be installed. PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) : Unable to find End of Central Dir Record signature